# Use Rake to create webhooks in Shopify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify, ruby-on-rails-5

Currently, if I add/remove a webhook from my application, for it to reflect in shopify app, the user has to reinstall the app. I need a way to avoid that so I thought I'd use rake.

For this I'm using the [Rails ShopifyAPP](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app). My app uses Rails 5.

**config/application.rb:**

```
...

config.after_initialize do
  Rails.application.load_tasks
  Rake::Task['shopifyapp:shopify_webhooks'].invoke
end

...
```

**lib/tasks/shopify_webhooks.rake:**

```
namespace :shopifyapp  do
  desc "create webhooks in shopify"
  task :shopify_webhooks do
    ShopifyApp.configure do |config|
      config.webhooks = [
        {topic: 'carts/update', address: 'https://some-external-address', format: 'json'},        
      ]
    end
    puts "works" # outputs when server restarts
  end
end
```

My 6th sense tells me something is not right with the rake file. Am I missing something? What's the issue? Webhooks are not creating.

If I add a new webhook in `config/initializers/shopify_app.rb`, it will work only if the app is reinstalled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a valid authentication token to the Shop, in your rake task just connect to the Shop, and use the API to create the webhook. It is very easy to do.

```
ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(ShopifyAPI::Session.new(shop,token))
ShopifyAPI::Webhook.create(topic: 'orders/paid', address: 'https:foo', format: 'json')
```

I think that is more inline with how to use rake than to try and mimic Rails inside a rake task.

Comment: Thanks, David. I'll try this and report later.

Comment: Hi. Just tried this out but where `shop` and `token` comes from?

Comment: I understand. How to get the current shop in the rake file?

Answer (score 0):

@David Lazar is correct but not that clear for a noob like me. I wanted the all connected shop to get the update I need to get all connected shop from the database first:

```
namespace :shopifyapp  do
  desc "create webhooks in shopify"
  task :shopify_webhooks do
    Shop.all.each do |s|
      domain = s.shopify_domain
      token = s.shopify_token

      ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(ShopifyAPI::Session.new(domain, token))
      ShopifyAPI::Webhook.create(
        topic: 'carts/update',address: 'https://foo ...,
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Now I can run the rake task from the console or when the server restarts! Nice. Not sure about performance if I have thousands of users (shops).

Comment: Rake tasks are not meant to be performant when the fact is, they are just tasks. If you have to update 1000 shops in a loop, you're network bound anyway, so it matters not whether you're in Rails or rake console.

Comment: I see. So instead of telling 1000 shops to reinstall your app, what's the best way?

Comment: As you did it! I have Apps with over 1000 shops connected and I am always tinkering with them this way... command-line FTW with Rake... it is the best.

Comment: Yes. Ive remove the command from startup so I manually do it in the console ;)